# Java how to handle a \ on input

Tags: java, filesystems

I am currently trying to split a String folder. I get the value from a file system and it usually looks something like EAM\Testing.

```
String folder = "EAM\Testing"

String[] parts = folder.split("\\");
```

I know \ has special rules to it in java.

```
String folder = "EAM\\Testing"

String[] parts = folder.split("\\\\");
```

(I know the code above would work if I could control what the input looked like)

My problem is that I can not control what string folder is as input from a location of a file.

Is there a way to get this to work where folder only has one \ in it?

This is for a recycle bin component I am writing for Documentum a enterprise management system. When a document is deleted and the folder doesn't exist anymore I want to recreate it and inorder to recreate it the folder names must be seperate as I have to create them one at a time.

Here is how I get the name of the folder.

```
File f = new File(relationRecord.getRepeatingString(
                "dp_original_folder_paths",
                i));
```

(This gives an input such as `\EAM\testing`

```
String folder1 = f.toString();
```

I then get rid of the first `\` by

```
String folder = folder1.substring(1);
```

Which gives me `EAM\testing`

Comment: Escaping only applies when you're writing out the literal yourself. If you get the string from some other source, such as user input, you don't need to worry about it. Grabbing the user input of "\" in a console, for instance, will give you an equivalent string of "\\" (if you'd typed it as a literal.)

Comment: I don't really get what you are asking, can clarify a bit more? perhaps with examples

Comment: I added a little more to my question hope that it helps

Comment: "I have to create them one at a time." - Why? There's [`File#mkdirs` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs--) which creates all folders including parent ones, if they don't exist.

Comment: Documentum doesnt act like a normal file system and mkdirs will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Well if this is literally a file path, you should [consider using the `Path` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathClass.html), it'll make your life easier.

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\home\\joe\\foo");

System.out.format("toString: %s%n", path.toString());
System.out.format("getFileName: %s%n", path.getFileName());
System.out.format("getName(0): %s%n", path.getName(0));
System.out.format("getNameCount: %d%n", path.getNameCount());
System.out.format("subpath(0,2): %s%n", path.subpath(0,2));
System.out.format("getParent: %s%n", path.getParent());
System.out.format("getRoot: %s%n", path.getRoot());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second option

```
String[] parts = folder.split("\\\\");
```

Should work fine for your input string. When you write a string literal like `"EAM\\Testing"`, the resulting string has only one slash. You can read some details on escape sequences in Java [there](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

The reason you need four slashes in `split` is because `\` is an escape character both for string literals and regular expressions ([`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) accepts regular expression as its argument)

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something like this -

```
String s = "EAM\\testing";
String a[] = s.split("\\\\");
```

Here you duplicate the backslash once for the String (since \ is an escape character for String) and again for the regex for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be "how can I remove a leading `\` from a string:

```
folder = folder.replaceAll("^\\\\", "");
```

This searches for a back slash at the start if the string, and if found replaces it with nothing (ie deletes it).

Regarding backslash vs forward slash characters in paths, java handles both.